# Does StandardScaler() maintain order?

Tags: python-2.7, preprocessor, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I'm using StandardScaler to transform data before providing training dataset to clustering model.

```
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_train)
```

Assume, clf is the unsupervised cluster model, I'm predicting the labels as follows:

```
y = clf.predict(X)
```

Question: How do I combine "y" and "X_train" numpy arrays? I'm not sure if StandardScaler() maintains the order within the matrix. So, will this work?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(X_train), np.array(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of the scikit-learn transformers maintain samples' ordering. Otherwise they would be useless.